# to sort a collection that I do not know what type does it have?

Tags: c#, collections

Is there a way in .NET that I can sort my collection when I do not know what types of objects at run time I will pass to this collection and also by avoiding Reflection.

any thoughts?

Comment: You'll get better answers when you add a little more details. Like: What do you know about those objects? Will they be sorted in multiple ways? etc.

Comment: If those types don't share a common base type or interface how do you intend to compare them?

Comment: @Darin : members of each collection will have the same type. Just I dunno what the type is. I think I will go with the Answer that Henk provied.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do need some way of comparing elements. The usual way is to demand IComparable:

```
class MyCollection<T> where T : IComparable<T>
{
}
```

or use an IComparer, either for the Sorting method or the constructor:

```
class MyCollection<T> // where T : IComparable<T>
{
    void Sort(IComparer<T> comparer) 
    {
        if  (comparer.Compare(a, b) > 0) { ... }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you use an `ArrayList` collection?

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
list.Add("R");
list.Add("B");
list.Add("G");
list.Sort();
//produces "B","G","R"

list.Clear();
list.Add(100);
list.Add(10);
list.Add(9);
list.Sort();
//produces 9,10,100
```

Comment: Because:

List.Add("R");
List.Add("B");
List.Add("G");
List.Add(100);
List.Add(new Apple());
List.Add(new Orange());

Comment: because they are not always regular types like string, int,etc...most of the times they are objects of the classes I have defined.

Comment: The implement IComparable<> to the base class (or interface)